# Reading CSV with multiple types, including multi dim list (or numpy), into python dictionary?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV file with the following format:

```
name,value,isTrue,multiDimArray
Paul, 10, True,[[0,0],[10.5,100],[135.5,87.5]]
Amy, 3, True,[[0,0]]
Jack, 9, False,[[100,100],[100.5,22.5],[15.5,87]]
```

I'd like to import this file into a python dictionary (UPDATE: a list of dictionaries might be better, I can probably work with either) with the correct data types (i.e. in this case: String, Integer, Boolean, list (or numpy array)). I can alter the CSV format some if needed as I'll be creating these.

I've been struggling with both np.genfromtxt and using csv.DictReader. The former either gives me errors or I end up with a weird void data type. The latter works if I put " " around the mutli-dim lists, but everything is a string.

```
with open(inputFile,'r') as file:
   csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)
   data = [row for row in csv_reader]
```

Comment: You should make sure that the column separator is different from the python list separators. Meaning: it can't be coma `,` or space ` ` just in case. Use tabs i.e.

Comment: Good point. Maybe that's why I had to enclose the list in " " to get it to work with DictReader. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to handle types and just leaves everything as a string.

Comment: CSV is *text*. There are no types in a csv. You should consider using an alternative format if you want to handle things more exotic than differentiating between numeric and text types. Use picke, or maybe parquet or even JSON. Don't use CSV

Comment: "Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to handle types and just leaves everything as a string" *because there are no types in a CSV, there is only text separated into rows and columns*. As noted, the method that you used to generate this CSV didn't do that corretly, because you didn't use quoting correctly (was this created manually?). Using the `csv` module would have at least handled that correctly.

Comment: I agree with what darked89 said. If you have that sorted out, you can use ast.literal_eval(x) (an inbuilt method) to convert a string to a proper python type. Note that real strings still need to be escaped for that, since python can't know whether you are interested in the boolean value True or the string "True", so only use it on columns you know of they don't contain strings.

Comment: but fundamentally, I cannot emphasize this enough, you shouldn't use CSV here.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: that isn't CSV. It would need a custom parser to read. If you have some control over this format, however ...

CSV presents a text representation of data. The user needs to know through some external means how each value should be interpreted. In your case, your program would need to know that `multiDimArray` isn't just text, but an encoding of something else. There is nothing inherent in, say, `"[0,0]"` that means it's a list of integers. Maybe it's some ASCII art. The writer of the CSV file would have to state what that string is.

It would be reasonable to use a JSON string. That's pretty common. Or even an embedded CSV file that needs to be exploded to get to the data. That's the choice of whatever writes the file and the reader code just has to know what the rules are.

There is nothing inherent in your "name" or "value" columns either. A program like Pandas may use heuristics to guess what the values are. But there is an inherent fragility there. You should know your data types a-priori and be specific about them in your code, IMHO.

But most importantly, this needs to be written as a valid CSV and your example is not. There should not be any extraneous spaces and all of those commas inside the multiDimArray values need to be escaped somehow. You could quote the entire value, or add backslashes before for the comma, or use a different separator like "|" so that the commas don't need escaping at all.

The benefit of strictly conforming to CSV rules (vague as they may be) is that you can then use any number of tools to manage them. The stuff you have so far couldn't be written to SQL or read in Excel.

Answer (score -1):

This is just a hack which may keep you going: instead of wrestling with lines of text in Python you may make the input "pythonic" and just read it using import.

For example:

```
foobar_dict = {
"Paul": (10, True, [[0, 0], [10.5, 100], [135.5, 87.5]]),
"Amy": (3, True, [[0, 0]]),
"Jack": (9, False, [[100, 100],[100.5, 22.5], [15.5, 87]]),
}
```

Spaces are optional, string quotes obligatory.
If `name` values are not unique, simply switch from dictionary to a list of tuples.